# Why does hasOwnProperty('toString') not work on an object?

Tags: javascript, object, hasownproperty

I recently watched a guide and wanted better understanding about the concept of hasOwnProperty.

According to Mozilla:

"The hasOwnProperty() method returns a boolean indicating whether the object has the specified property as own **(not inherited) property**."

I created an object

```
var test = {yes:function(){}}
```

and then did

```
test.hasOwnProperty('toString')
```

and it returned false.  Its because toString is a method that i did NOT create right inside test right?

But then if I log hasOwnProperty to an array and pass length, so

```
var arr1 = new Array
arr.hasOwnProperty('length') //appears to return true
```

It returns true, but I never declared length.

I thought hasOwnProperty only works on properties NOT inherited -

so why does using hasownprop('length') on an array return true when the array object inherits the length property,

but

```
var test = {yes:function(){}}
test.hasOwnProperty('toString') //false
```

why^ does this return false?  toString is method on the object's prototype and I see it when I log it into the Google Chrome Console

Comment: The `length` property on arrays is not inherited. Every array has its own length.

Comment: `toString` is inherited (from the object's prototype). All (vanilla) objects have the same `toString` method.

Comment: @melpomene Actually one could imagine `.length` being a special getter/setter property on `Array.prototype`. Of course you're right, it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

> Its because toString is a method that I did NOT create right inside test right?

Yeah, objects created from object literals only do have the own properties that are declared in the literal.

But that you did not explicitly declare a property does not mean that it is inherited, or that it doesn't exist. Arrays do have an own `.length` property that is basically created by the array constructor - in the `new Array` call.

Imagine the following:

```
function Test() {
    this.prop = "some value";
}
var x = new Test;
console.log(x.hasOwnProperty("prop")) // what do you expect?
```